# Approximating an MVC using XSL, PHP, Perl, XML.

Tags: php, xml, perl, xslt

Problem : I have a XML snippet stored in a DB which I want to combine with several other fields from the DB and present them using HTML from PHP.

My Solution: 
I have Perl Backend script which does

```
$query = "select id, description, xml_content, name from table where id = '$id'";
```

then modifies the XML to include these field.

```
$xml_content =~ s|<Record>|<Record name="$name" id="$id" desc="$desc">|i;
```

I then use XSL file to transform this to

```
  <xsl:output method="html"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <body>
        <form action="info.php" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
          <label for="id">Display xml for: </label>
          <input type="text" name="id" value="" id="id" size="40"/>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Display it! &#x02192;"/></p>
            </form>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
   </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="doc:Record">
    <p>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="./@none">
          XML Content ID <xsl:value-of select="@id"/> NOT FOUND 
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          XML Content ID <xsl:value-of select="@id"/> Found  
         <xsl:value-of select="@desc"/> - <xsl:value-of select="@name"/> 
      </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>
```

I then use PHP to get the CGI vars and run the perl script and display the output.

```
<?php 
if (!empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $command = "getxml.pl --id=" . $_GET['id'];
    $process = proc_open($command, $descriptorspec, $pipes, null, $_SERVER);
    if (is_resource($process)) { 
        $line = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    } else { 
        $line = '<Record none="" desc="' . $command . '"></Record>';
    }
}

header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>';
echo '<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xmlinfo.xsl"?>';
echo "\n";

if (empty($command)) { 
    #Display the form only.
    $line = '<Record></Record >';
}
echo "$line \n";

?>
```

Since PHP was configured without xslt, this is the only I could think of to display the XML in HTML using PHP.

My question is:

1. Is there a way to remove the `<html><body><form>` part in XSL and put it into PHP. It would seem much cleaner that way.

Thanks.

Comment: That's a pretty crazy workflow! Can I ask, what parts of this process are important? Could you reimplement the whole thing using a web framework? If you give an example XML document I could mock up something in Perl, though I'm sure RoR (and probably even PHP) would have ways of doing it too.

Also is the final return supposed to be HTML or XML (I'm really asking about the headers). Maybe you could given an example response too.

Comment: Well the main thing is I want display some information in a browser (which means HTML I guess as final output) from a chunk of XML that is stored in the DB as well as other information from some other tables in the DB. The biggest and most important part is stored in XML, so I started from there.

Comment: I wanted to preserve as much of the XML as possible. I decided to grab all the other bits and convert/embed it into the big XML chunk. That's the Perl part. Then I thought about using the same Perl script to do the CGI part but decided it would be "cleaner(??)" to use PHP to do the call. That way I can use the Perl script from cli as well. And that's how I ended up using XML, XSL, Perl and PHP. Quite a stupid solution and not too elegant

Comment: As I work up an example, you can see where I'm going at an old blog post of mine: http://blogs.perl.org/users/joel_berger/2012/10/a-simple-mojoliciousdbi-example.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using an actual framework. The framework I use is [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us) for Perl, certainly others could also handle this. I setup several database handling methods (which you might be able to adapt from your original script). Then I use the built-in XML parser to update the record's attribute.

Finally I setup two routes. When run if you visit `/` you get your page as requested. Note that the XML has been escaped (in the template) so that it renders as text to the browser. This can be changed if you prefer some other form of display. If you visit `/record?id=1` you get the XML result directly. This is more useful for a RESTful interface.

Lets say you name it `app.pl`. To run it you can simply

```
./app.pl daemon
```

then visit `http://localhost:3000` to view using one of mojo's built-in servers (yes it does run under CGI too).

Or you can actually interact with the script. Say you want to just see one record at the command line

```
./app.pl get '/record?id=1'
```

or perhaps you want to insert something, the `helper`s are available via `eval`

```
./app.pl eval 'app->insert(2, "Something", "<Record>Something Else</Record>", "Name")'
```

Cool eh?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Mojolicious::Lite;
use Mojo::DOM;
use DBI;

# connect to database
use DBI;

helper db => sub { 
  state $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:database.db","","") or die "Could not connect";
};

# add helper methods for interacting with database
helper create_table => sub {
  my $self = shift;
  warn "Creating table 'records'\n";
  $self->db->do('CREATE TABLE records (id INT, description TEXT, xml_content TEXT, name VARCHAR(255));');
  $self->insert(1,'Description','<Record>Contents</Record>','Name');
};

helper select => sub {
  my $self = shift;
  my $sth = eval { $self->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM records WHERE id = ?') } || return undef;
  my $id = shift or return 0;
  $sth->execute($id);
  return $sth->fetchrow_hashref;
};

helper insert => sub {
  my $self = shift;
  my ($id, $description, $xml, $name) = @_;
  my $sth = eval { $self->db->prepare('INSERT INTO records VALUES (?,?,?,?)') } || return undef;
  $sth->execute($id, $description, $xml, $name);
  return 1;
};

# if statement didn't prepare, assume its because the table doesn't exist
defined app->select or app->create_table;

helper 'xml_by_id' => sub {
  my $self = shift;
  my $id = shift;

  my $row = $self->select($id) || {};
  return '<Record></Record>' unless keys %$row;

  my $xml = Mojo::DOM->new->xml(1)->parse( $row->{xml_content} );
  my $record = $xml->at('Record');

  for my $key ( qw/ name id description / ) {
    $record->{$key} = $row->{$key};
  }

  return wantarray ? ($xml, $row) : $xml;
};

any '/record' => sub {
  my $self = shift;
  my $id = $self->param('id') || $self->render_not_found;
  my $xml = $self->xml_by_id($id);
  $self->render( text => $xml, format => 'xml' );
};

any '/' => sub {
  my $self = shift;

  if ( my $id = $self->param('id') ) {
    my ($xml, $row) = $self->xml_by_id($id);
    $self->stash( id  => $id  );
    $self->stash( xml => $xml );
    $self->stash( row => $row );
  }

  $self->render('index');
};

app->start;

__DATA__

@@ index.html.ep
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Get XML</title></head>
<body>
  <form action="/" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <label for="id">Display xml for: </label>
    <input type="text" name="id" value="" id="id" size="40"/>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Display it! &#x02192;"/></p>
  </form>
  % if ( my $id = stash('id') ) {
    <p> XML Content ID <%= $id %>
      % my $row = stash('row');
      % if ( keys %$row ) {
        Found
        <%= $row->{description} %> - <%= $row->{name} %> 
      %} else {
        NOT FOUND
      %}
    </p>
    %= stash('xml')
  % }
</body>
</html>
```